# Hotlinking images in Outlook emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, images

I want to create an email with a signature that contains an external image.  For example, I would like to always include my SuperUser flair in my signature like so: https://superuser.com/users/flair/53525.png

This can be done if I insert an image and select the above source.  The problem occurs when I copy the image and paste it into the body of a new email.  Outlook creates an embedded version and breaks the link to the original email.

How can an image be pasted into Outlook and NOT be embedded (ie: the link to the original image is maintained?)

Answer (score 0):

What are you pasting it into?  Why do you need to copy it?  Why not manually insert an image with source of https://superuser.com/users/flair/53525.png